# Binding nullable parameters

Tags: micronaut

Considering the following (simplified) form

```
<form id="simple-form" action="/requests" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="hidden" name="providerId" value="{{providerId}}" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

when this form is submited without a providerId value, it is binded correctly if method parameter is an Optional

```
@Post(uri="/requests", consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Transactional
public HttpResponse doSimple(@Body Optional<Long> providerId) {
    ...
}
```

but failed if I use the @Nullable annotation (with this error message : "Failed to convert argument [providerId] for value [] due to: For input string: \"\"")

```
@Post(uri="/requests", consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Transactional
public HttpResponse doSimple(@Body @Nullable Long providerId) {
    ...
}
```

Aren't they suppose to act the same ?

Thank in advance for your advices.

Comment: Can you file an issue with a reproducible sample?

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I will file the issue. I noticed that the problem does not occurs when the type to bind is string. 

public HttpResponse doSimple(@Body @Nullable String providerId) works.